# TCP sender machine receiver-window-size shrinking to 0 on windows machine after sending tiny amounts of data for a few minutes

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I'm writing an app that works on a windows laptop that sends TCP bytes in a loop as a "homemade keep-alive" message to keep a connection active (the server machine will disconnect after 15 seconds of no TCP data received). The "server machine" will send the laptop small chunks of data (about .5K bytes/second) as long as a connection is alive (according to the server documentation, this is ideally this is an "echo" packet, but I was unable to find how this is accomplished in .NET). My problem is that when I view this data in Wireshark I can see good network activity, then, after a few minutes, the "win" (receive window size available on the laptop) shrinks from 65K to 0 in increments of about 240 bytes each packet. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it? I can't seem to get the "keep-alive" flags in .Net to work, so this was supposed to be my workaround. I do not see any missed ACK messages, and my data rate is about 2Kb/sec, so I don't understand why the laptop window size is dropping. I definitely assume there is a misconception on my part about TCP and or windows/.NET use of TCPsockets since I have no experience with TCP (I've always used UDP).

```
                    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(iPEndpoint);
                    //Socket s = client.Client; none of these flags actually work on the keep alive feature
                    //s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                    //s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveInterval, 10);
                    //s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveInterval, 10);
    
                    // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                    // Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    
                    IPAddress ipAdd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10"); 
                    IPEndPoint ipEndPoin = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 13000);
                    client.Connect(ipEndPoin);
    
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    
                    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
                    bool finished = false;
                    while (!finished)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                            Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        }
                        catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
                        {
                            if (ioe.InnerException is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
                            {
                                client.Dispose();
                                client = new TcpClient(iPEndpoint);
                                client.Connect(ipEndPoin); 
                                stream = client.GetStream(); 
                                Console.Write("reconnected");
                                // this imediately fails again after exiting this catch to go back to the while loop because send window is still 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Are you actually reading the data on the other side? TCP will stop sending data if the other side can't properly receive it.

Comment: And of course, you should also be reading the data the server sends you on the client. Remember, TCP isn't send-and-forget, unlike UDP. You can't just ignore the data that's coming your way.

Comment: @Luaan Thank you for responding. I don't have access to the server machine, but I do see a handshake coming from that machine when I do my "fake keep-alive" packet. The server machine does send data to me after I connect, and nothing looks unusual about that window size (the server machine keeps a nearly constant window size). My laptop window size shrinks after a random amount of packets. My only means of inspection is Wireshark on my laptop.

I intent to read the data stream once I get this "keep-alive" working, but I didn't want to make the question any more convoluted.

Comment: The window size is set by the other end. It will shrink to '0' when the other end is full and needs to process the received data. It will grow back up when the other end has processed enough data to again receive more.

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you mean by "fake keep-alive" packet? Does the server understand what you're sending? You can't just send random data and expect things to work - don't forget that unlike UDP, TCP isn't about independent messages - it's about streams of data. If you're sending nonsensical data (or worse, partial messages), the whole connection gets quite unpredictable.

Comment: RonMaupin the "server" receive window stays constant, the "laptop" receive window is dropping to 0, and I'm assuming it is something wrong with my code.
@Luaan I just need to send a TCP packet to the server (the server is an embedded device that only requires some type of TCP packet in order for the connection to stay alive). Idealy this is an "echo" packet, but I was unable to find any .NET documentation on this.

Comment: By the way, the TCP echo server would be on port 7, assuming you have such a server configured on your host. You would need to establish a connection to port 7 of the echo server. If you are just wanting keepalives, you send them (by default) every two hours. They are discussed in _[RFC 1122, page 101](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1122#page-101)_.

Comment: Again, TCP works on streams, not messages. Those aren't independent packets you can ignore as you please - if you don't read from the stream, they're kept in the buffer. And as the buffer fills, _you_ start (automatically) sending information that the other side should stop sending data, because you're not processing it fast enough. It's obvious you're still trying to treat TCP as "weird" UDP. It's not. UDP deals with messages - that either arrive or don't. TCP assembles the IP packets into a continuous stream. Just keep reading the stream and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really be familiar with *[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)*, which is the definition of TCP. It explains the wondow and how it is used for flow control:

> Flow Control:
>
> TCP provides a means for the receiver to govern the amount of data
> sent by the sender.  This is achieved by returning a "window" with
> every ACK indicating a range of acceptable sequence numbers beyond the
> last segment successfully received.  The window indicates an allowed
> number of octets that the sender may transmit before receiving further
> permission.

-and-

> To govern the flow of data between TCPs, a flow control mechanism is
> employed.  The receiving TCP reports a "window" to the sending TCP.
> This window specifies the number of octets, starting with the
> acknowledgment number, that the receiving TCP is currently prepared to
> receive.

-and-

> Window:  16 bits
>
> The number of data octets beginning with the one indicated in the
> acknowledgment field which the sender of this segment is willing to
> accept.

The window size is dictated by the receiver of the data in its ACK segments where it acknowledges receipt of the data. If your laptop receive window shrinks to `0`, it is setting the window to that because it has no more space to receive, and it needs time to process and free up space in the receive buffer. When it has more space, it will send an ACK segment with a larger window.

> ```
> Segment Receive  Test
> Length  Window
> ------- -------  -------------------------------------------
>
>    0       0     SEG.SEQ = RCV.NXT
>
>    0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>
>   >0       0     not acceptable
>
>   >0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>               or RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ+SEG.LEN-1 < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
> ```
>
> Note that when the receive window is zero no segments should be
> acceptable except ACK segments.  Thus, it is be possible for a TCP to
> maintain a zero receive window while transmitting data and receiving
> ACKs.  However, even when the receive window is zero, a TCP must
> process the RST and URG fields of all incoming segments.

Comment: I updated my question because I was not clear that it is the LAPTOP RECEIVE WINDOW  that actually is shrinking, I'm sorry about that confusion. The laptop window size decreases to 0 (the ACK messages from laptop shiow this). So my laptop is sending dummy data. The server receive window never drops much. My confusion is "why" is the laptop's TCP receive window decreasing to 0? Is my code wrong? The server documentation states that I should use an "echo" packet, rather than sending nonsense data to keep the connection alive, but .net has no docs on this

Comment: OK, the server is sending data to your laptop. Are you processing the data in the laptop so that the receive buffer is emptied? It sounds like that data is simply filling the buffer, and the windows shrinks as it does so: "_the "win" (receive window size available on the laptop) shrinks from 65K to 0 in increments of about 240 bytes each packet._" It sounds like the server is sending about 240 data bytes per segment, and that is your buffer filling.

Comment: I'm guessing you are 100% correct on that, but I'll look for documentation on emptying the buffer just to be sure. With UDP I could just ignore packets, but with TCP that isn't true? what is even stranger is that when I watch this happening in Wireshark the strangest thing happens: I see the receive window go from 65K down to 60K then it shoots back up to 65K. This phenomenon loops through several iterations until, on the final iteration, the receive buffer goes from 65K down to 0 at a constant rate. Why would the receive buffer not just go to 0 on the first iteration?

Comment: The OS may be expanding it before it until it reaches a limit, then it shrinks down to nothing.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, ill accept your answer and upvote after I get home to verify. Would you update your answer to help other dummies like me?

Comment: I'm not sure how to update it. It discusses what the receive window is and how it is communicated for flow control, which seems to be your problem.